# VBA equivalent to IF(OR()) formula in Excel

Tags: ms-access, vba

In Excel, I have a function that utilises the `IF()` and `OR()` functions. I wish to write an equivalent function in Access VBA. How do I go about writing the code for this?

```
=IF(OR($X9=1,$X9=2,$X9=3),Y9-1,Y9)
```

I intend to use this if function as a module:

```
Function iyear(month as string, year as string) as string
```

So in this case, $X9 will be the month, and Y9 will be the year.

Comment: [What Have You Tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) For starters, look up `If` and `Or` in VBA help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

well in VBA you could do something like this

```
Function iyear(month As Long, year As Long) As Long
    If month = 1 Or month = 2 Or month = 3 Then
        iyear = year - 1
    Else
        iyear = year
    End If
End Function

Sub Main()
    MsgBox "month = 1, year = 2013" & vbNewLine & "iyear returns: " & iyear(1, 2013) & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
            "month = 4, year = 2013" & vbNewLine & "iyear returns: " & iyear(4, 2013)
End Sub
```